# Ensure all perceivable text is included in an ARIA landmark

Tags: html, accessibility

I have created a html page when i do the accessibility testing i got some ARIA-landmarks suggesstions like below

Ensure all perceivable text is included in an ARIA landmark.

Using that i have added some landmarks for the heading tags like below

```
<div class="sign-up-title-container">
  <h1 class="sign-up-title" role="heading" aria-level="1" aria-label="Sign up now" style="color: #000000; background-color: #fcb913">
     Sign up now
   </h1>
</div>
```

```
<div class="sw-cta-container-v1">
  <p class="sw-cta-sub-text-v1" role="presentation" aria-label="Already a member?">
Already a member?
  <span>
    <a class="sw-cta-text-v1" role="button" aria-label="Log In" href="/en-us/login/?redir=/en-us/home/">Log In</a>
  </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Based on the suggestions i have added the role as heading with aria-level="1" and aria-label="Sign up now"

But after running the test again i am facing the same message

**Ensure all perceivable text is included in an ARIA landmark.**

Not sure what i am doing wrong. Could anyone suggest me what is mistake i am doing.

Comment: Is the message really telling you that not all perceivable text is included, or is it just reminding you to check?

Comment: It tells that in Signup now and Already a member tags has no perceivable text included

Answer (score 2):

The example code does not include any landmark, so the message will persist. The added ARIA attributes are harmful and deteriorating accessibility, you should probably remove them all.

> A landmark is an *abstract* role for a *section of content* that is important enough that users will likely want to be able to navigate to the section easily and have it included in a dynamically generated summary of the page. Landmarks allow assistive technologies to navigate and to find content quickly.

From [ARIA: landmark role on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/landmark_role), emphasis was added for this answer.

Since `landmark` is an abstract role, you need to use one of the [derived roles](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#landmark_roles) for your section, like `form` or `region`.

Any `<form>` is already a landmark role, and should have a helpful accessible name. This seems relevant to the example at hand, were two forms (sign-up and log-in) exist.

```
<form class="sign-up-title-container" aria-labelledby="sign-up-title">
  <h1 class="sign-up-title" id="sign-up-title" style="color: #000000; background-color: #fcb913">
     Sign up now
   </h1>
</form>
```

This will provide a [named](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby) landmark, that users of assistive technology can directly find in a list of page landmarks and navigate to it.

---

For the issues with the suggested ARIA attributes.

[Using ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#firstrule) states some foundational rules:

> If you can use a native HTML element [HTML51] or attribute with the semantics and behavior you require already built in, instead of re-purposing an element and adding an ARIA role, state or property to make it accessible, then do so.

> Do not change native semantics, unless you really have to.

```html
Don’t <h1 role="heading" aria-level="1">
Do <h1>
```

Is explicitly defining the role and level again, that the `<h1>` element already has. It’s only a more verbose version and should be avoided. The same goes for the next part, which also achieves nothing different, as the accessible name of an element is by default it’s text contents:

```html
Don’t <h1 aria-label="Sign up now">Sign up now</h1>
Do <h1>Sign up now</h1>
```

```html
Don’t <p role="presentation">
Do <p>
```

A `<p>` element has an implicit role of `paragraph`. By changing it to [presentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/presentation_role), any semantics are taken away from this element, which makes navigating the document harder for users of assistive technology.

> The presentation role and its synonym none remove an element's implicit ARIA semantics from being exposed to the accessibility tree.

Naming presentational elements is prohibited as per ARIA standard, so `aria-label` must be removed.

```html
<a role="button" href="…
```

This is taking away the [`link` role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/link_role) that `<a href>` already has. It helps users understand that interacting with the element will cause some form of navigation.

Instead, the [`button` role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role) is applied:

> The `button` role is for clickable elements that trigger a response when activated by the user.

It can make sense to do so, if only visibility of a part of the UI is changed. “button or link” is covered to a large extend on the web.

Answer (score 2):

@andy has some good info in his answer, especially regarding all the extra ARIA that was added to the code to try to "fix" the landmark issue.

You didn't say what tool you used to scan the page to check the accessibility, but in any event, tools that **recommend** that all content be contained in a landmark is purely a **suggestion** and **not** a WCAG or accessibility requirement.

You're certainly encouraged to have everything in a landmark but you don't have to. If you do want landmarks, try to use native HTML elements first before resorting to adding a [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions). So your page structure might be something like this:

```
<header>
  <!-- company logo, main top navigation elements, etc -->
  <nav>
    <!-- main top navigation -->
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <!-- body of page -->
</main>

<footer>
  <!-- typical footer links -->
</footer>
```

All of the HTML elements in the example above have default landmark roles:

- [<header>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element) (`banner` landmark if on page level)
- [<nav>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-nav-element) (`navigation` role)
- [<main>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) (`main` role)
- [<footer>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-footer-element) (`contentinfo` role if on page level)